# How to extract text entered in text input using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an HTML element `<input id="input-id" type="text" value="initial">`.
After loading the page I can get text from this element using, for example, `driver.find_element_by_id("input-id").get_attribute("value")`.

But then I click on this element and change the text inside (to "edited", for example). Nothing in DOM changes, including value of the `value` attribute
(i.e. `driver.find_element_by_id("input-id").get_attribute("value")` still returns "initial" and element in DOM looks like `<input id="input-id" type="text" value="initial">`)

How can I extract value that is now visible in browser (i.e. string "edited")? Do I need to execute some JavaScript or anything?

Answer (score 3):

That value doesn't change when you input some new text.
You could try to do just this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("input-id").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: But innerHTML also does not change when I enter text, does it? I mean, nothing appears between <input> and </input>.

Comment: @StacyMiller You should test it for you case. However why do you want to get the text that YOU put in the field?

Comment: I already tested and nothing appears, that is why I am asking. I need it because it seems more clear from the code style point in my case. However, I may do some code refactoring.

Comment: I understand. I'm actually using Selenium for a project of mine, so I will try to understand better what's going on here and in case update the info.